# Is there any way to know if a user's InApp and Subscriptions purchases has already been restored on a fresh app install?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Is there any way to know if Android has **correctly** finished fetching the user's purchases on an app fresh install, after running `adb shell pm clear com.android.vending`?

- `billingClient.isReady` returns `true`;
- `billingClient.queryPurchases(SkuType.INAPP)` returns `BillingResponse.OK` and an empty list;
- `billingClient.queryPurchases(SkuType.SUBS)` returns `BillingResponse.OK` and an empty list (even though the user has an active subscription).

When the user tries to purchase a subscription that he has already bought (considering the conditions mentioned), the following error appears:

[image]

Obs.: I want to avoid using `billingClient.queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(String, PurchaseHistoryResponseListener)`.

Answer (score 0):

Each `Purchase` item has a `purchaseToken` associated with it. If your app has a server, you can tie the `purchaseToken` to a user on your own server. Alternatively you can [attach a payload](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#attach_a_developer_payload) when you acknowledge the `Purchase`. That payload can be a unique string (e.g. userId) that can help you identify the specific user.

So you have two options:

1. Keep track of the `purchaseToken` in your own server
2. Attach a unique [developer payload](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#attach_a_developer_payload) to the purchase when you acknowledge.